# How to set file control value (file path) using java applet

Tags: javascript, java, html, applet

I got file path using `JFileChooser` in applet. I just want to set it in html file control. Is it possible to set file path in html file control so that it will be submitted to server while html form submission?

Comment: There might be some java - javascript stuff allowing that, but browser support for applets is going away and you might have to think about slightly other architecture e.g. using java web start

Comment: Thanks @ Stefan Hegny